# how to add H1 in title site?

Tags: wp-blog-header.php

based on SEO inspector said that my homepage doesnt cointain H1 heading...

**this code from developer source i taken from mozilla browser**

```
<title>interiordapur - Ahlinya Kitchen Set &amp; Desain Interior</title>
```

**I check source my website no H1 detected. and I check my theme header.php that the code such below**

```
<?php
```

/**
 * Setting global variables for all theme options saved values
 *
 * @since Construction Field 1.0.0
 *
 * @param null
 * @return void
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'construction_field_set_global' ) ) :
    function construction_field_set_global() {
        /*Getting saved values start*/
        $construction_field_saved_theme_options = construction_field_get_theme_options();
        $GLOBALS['construction_field_customizer_all_values'] = $construction_field_saved_theme_options;
        /*Getting saved values end*/
    }
endif;
add_action( 'construction_field_action_before_head', 'construction_field_set_global', 0 );

/**
 * Doctype Declaration
 *
 * @since Construction Field 1.0.0
 *
 * @param null
 * @return void
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'construction_field_doctype' ) ) :
    function construction_field_doctype() {
        ?>
        >

/**
 * Code inside head tage but before wp_head funtion
 *
 * @since Construction Field 1.0.0
 *
 * @param null
 * @return void
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'construction_field_before_wp_head' ) ) :

```
function construction_field_before_wp_head() {
    ?>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="//gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php
}
```

endif;
add_action( 'construction_field_action_before_wp_head', 'construction_field_before_wp_head', 10 );

/**
 * Add body class
 *
 * @since Construction Field 1.0.0
 *
 * @param null
 * @return null
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'construction_field_body_class' ) ) :

```
function construction_field_body_class( $construction_field_body_classes ) {

    global $construction_field_customizer_all_values;
    $construction_field_enable_animation = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-enable-animation'];
    $construction_field_feature_info_display_options = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-feature-info-display-options'];

    /*wow animation*/
    if( 1 != $construction_field_enable_animation ){
        $construction_field_body_classes[] = 'acme-animate';
    }
    $construction_field_body_classes[] = construction_field_sidebar_selection();

    if( 'hide' != $construction_field_feature_info_display_options ){
        $construction_field_body_classes[] = esc_attr( $construction_field_feature_info_display_options );
    }
    return $construction_field_body_classes;
}
```

endif;
add_action( 'body_class', 'construction_field_body_class', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Start site div
 *
 * @since Construction Field 1.0.0
 *
 * @param null
 * @return null
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'construction_field_site_start' ) ) :

```
function construction_field_site_start() {
    ?>
    <div class="site" id="page">
    <?php
}
```

endif;
add_action( 'construction_field_action_before', 'construction_field_site_start', 20 );

/**
 * Skip to content
 *
 * @since Construction Field 1.0.0
 *
 * @param null
 * @return null
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'construction_field_skip_to_content' ) ) :

```
function construction_field_skip_to_content() {
    ?>
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'construction-field' ); ?></a>
    <?php
}
```

endif;
add_action( 'construction_field_action_before_header', 'construction_field_skip_to_content', 10 );

/**
 * Main header
 *
 * @since Construction Field 1.0.0
 *
 * @param null
 * @return null
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'construction_field_header' ) ) :
    function construction_field_header() {
        global $construction_field_customizer_all_values;
        $construction_field_enable_header_top = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-enable-header-top'];
        $construction_field_nav_class = '';
        $construction_field_enable_sticky = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-enable-sticky'];
        if( 1 == $construction_field_enable_sticky ){
            $construction_field_nav_class .= ' construction-field-sticky';
        }
        $construction_field_feature_info_display_options = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-feature-info-display-options'];
        if( 1 == $construction_field_enable_header_top ){
            ?>

```
                            if( 'left' == $construction_field_header_top_menu_display_selection ){
                                do_action('construction_field_action_top_menu');
                            }
                            if( 'left' == $construction_field_header_top_social_display_selection ){
                                do_action('construction_field_action_social_links');
                            }
                            if( 'left' == $construction_field_header_top_news_display_selection ){
                                do_action('construction_field_action_newsnotice');
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <?php
                            if( 'right' == $construction_field_header_top_menu_display_selection ){
                                do_action('construction_field_action_top_menu');
                            }
                            if( 'right' == $construction_field_header_top_social_display_selection ){
                                do_action('construction_field_action_social_links');
                            }
                            if( 'right' == $construction_field_header_top_news_display_selection ){
                                do_action('construction_field_action_newsnotice');
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <div class="navbar at-navbar <?php echo ('alternative-info-menu' != $construction_field_feature_info_display_options? esc_attr( $construction_field_nav_class ) : '' );?>" id="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <?php
                if( 'alternative-info-menu' != $construction_field_feature_info_display_options ){
                    ?>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                    <?php
                }
                $construction_field_display_site_logo = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-display-site-logo'];
                $construction_field_display_site_title = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-display-site-title'];
                $construction_field_display_site_tagline = $construction_field_customizer_all_values['construction-field-display-site-tagline'];

                if( 1== $construction_field_display_site_logo || 1 == $construction_field_display_site_title || 1 == $construction_field_display_site_tagline ):
                    if ( 1 == $construction_field_display_site_logo && function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ):
                        the_custom_logo();
                    endif;
                    if ( 1== $construction_field_display_site_title  ):
                        if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                            <h1 class="site-title">
                                <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                            </h1>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <p class="site-title">
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                            </p>
                        <?php endif;
                    endif;
                    if ( 1== $construction_field_display_site_tagline  ):
                        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                        if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                            <p class="site-description"><?php echo esc_html( $description ); ?></p>
                        <?php endif;
                    endif;
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="at-beside-navbar-header">
                <?php
                if( 'alternative-info-menu' == $construction_field_feature_info_display_options ){
                    do_action( 'construction_field_action_feature_info' );
                }
                else{
                    construction_field_primary_menu();
                }
                ?>
            </div>
```

can some one help how to fix it???

Comment: BTW... You have to `endif`s in there, but only one opening `if`... What is the condition in the first if, that you haven’t posted in here?

Comment: I update from my theme... would you please check it and where is the mistake point???

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake or a typo:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) :
```

It should be:

```
if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) :
```

You want to put h1 in both: static front page and blog index.

Your condition with `&&` won’t be true, if you use static page as front page.